# C# Entity Framework - Where Inside Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I have object called **Project** that has a list of hours (which is list made up of a **Work** objects) worked on that project. The **Work** object has a member called **WorkDate**, which is a day that you worked on that project. What i want to do is get a list of projects where the hours is between two dates. However, when i try to make this query in entity framework, i get the error below. Does anyone know how to write this query in entity frame work. I would hopefully like to achieve this with a single query and not load all the projects and sort them in my controller.

For a better understand of what I'm trying to do, where is an SQL example.

In SQL i would do this via a join. I have two tables **Projects** and **Work**. I would join Work and Projects on  **Work.project_ID** is equal to the **Project.ID** 
Then select all project rows where the Work.WorkDate is bewteen two dates .

ProjectController.cs

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetProjectsByDate()
{
    try
    {
            var min = new DateTime(2017, 3, 1); 
            var max = new DateTime(2017, 3, 15);
            var projects = await context.Projects
                .Include(p => p.Hours)
                .ThenInclude(w => w.Where(h => h.WorkDate < max && h.WorkDate > min))
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToListAsync(); 
             return Json(projects);
    }
}
```

Project.cs

```
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? TeamID { get; set; }
    public int? ManagerID { get; set; }
    public int? CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public double? Estimate { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeamID")]
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ManagerID")]
    public virtual User Manager { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
    public virtual User Creator { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Work> Hours { get; set; }


    public Project()
    {
        Hours = new List<Work>();
    }
}
```

Out put of projects

```
Message = "The property expression 'w => {from Work h in w where (([h].WorkDate < __max_0) AndAlso ([h].WorkDate > __min_1)) select [h]}' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. For more information on including related d...
```

Comment: `.SelectMany(p => p.Hours)` - you're only selecting the Hours property, and `Hours = new List<Work>();`. As `SelectMany` flattens the hours of all the projects into one list, I'm not clear why you have included that in the query?

Comment: @stuartd Right, i figured that is what is causing the list of Work objects. Do you know how i can get a list of projects where hours are in between two dates ?

Comment: Where **all** the hours are between the dates?

Comment: You should do w.Hours.Where

Comment: @stuartd updated my question, hopefully this is more clear.

Comment: You can't I believe have an expression in `ThenInclude`

Comment: @stuartd where can i have it?

Comment: Please look at one of the many questions on "include + where". This is asked at least once a week.

Comment: `Include` is for loading related data (so called eager loading) and is all or nothing. It's still unclear what are you trying to achieve. If you want to get projects based on `Hours` collection, just use `Where` with the appropriate criteria (`p.Hours.Any(...)` or `p.Hours.All(...)` etc.). If you also want their `Hours` collection to be populated with filtered data, that's another story. So what it should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have my VS running, but expecting something like following works:

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetProjectsByDate()
{
    try
    {
        var min = new DateTime(2017, 3, 1); 
        var max = new DateTime(2017, 3, 15);
        var projects = await context.Projects
            .Include(p => p.Hours)
            .Where(p => p.Hours.Any() && p.Hours.Where(w => w.WorkDate < max && w.WorkDate > min).Count() == p.Hours.Count)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToListAsync(); 
         return Json(projects);
    }
}
```

This code make sure to return all projects that all the Hours in them is between min and max.

PS: Also, just beware that it's highly recommended to use UTC time everywhere and only use Locale time when you're going to actually show the data to user.

Comment: This is returning all the projects. I was trying to not return all the projects. Just the ones where Hours had Work objects between two dates.

Comment: @John `.Where(p => p.Hours.Where(w => w.WorkDate < max && w.WorkDate > min).Count() == p.Hours.Count))` line should filter to return only projects that their Hours is between min and max.

Comment: var test = from t in projects
                           where t.Hours.Count() > 0
                           select t; // Shows null

Comment: @john So fixed the code to consider empty Hours also. And https://dotnetfiddle.net/eyI3Yl you can see the demo of it

Comment: I appreciate the help, i changed the where condition to be > 0 and it works as expected now. Thanks, are there any ramification/ performance issues of running a where inside a where ? 

.Where(p => p.Hours.Where(h => h.WorkDate < max && h.WorkDate > min).Count() > 0)

Comment: Spoke to soon, its not loading the correct data, ill give your fiddle example a try.

Comment: Performance-wise, yes, it's like a nested loop, so that increases your BigO, it'll be O(mn) where m is number of projects and n is number of Hours. As far as Hours.Count isn't large, it should be fine.

Comment: @John Just a reminder that if it worked for you, please mark it as the answer. IF not, hit me up in the chat and we can look at it.

Comment: Sorry it didn't, i'm going a different route via the join function. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I'm going to make your answer the solution because it does what i originally asked.

Answer (score 1):

use Z.EntityFramework.Plus library

> http://entityframework-plus.net/

Soo all you need is do this:

```
using Z.EntityFramework.Plus;

[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetProjectsByDate()
{
    try
    {
        var min = new DateTime(2017, 3, 1); 
        var max = new DateTime(2017, 3, 15);
        var projects = await context.Projects
            .IncludeFilter(p => p.Hours
                    .Where(w => w.WorkDate < max && w.WorkDate > min))
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToListAsync(); 
         return Json(projects);
    }
}
```

Now you can so aplly order by in your include for example too.

Answer (score 0):

Simple console app displaying it.

```
public class Project
  {        
    public int ID { get; set; }         
    public string ManagerName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Work> Hours { get; set; }

    public Project(int id, string managerName, List<Work> work)
    {
      ID = id;
      ManagerName = managerName;
      Hours = work;
    }
  }

  public class Work
  {
    public int WorkId { get; set; }
    public string WorkName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    public Work(int workId, string workName, DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
      WorkId = workId;
      WorkName = workName;
      Start = start;
      End = end;
    }
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      var dtToday = DateTime.Now.Date;

      var projectsAndWork = new List<Project>
      {
        new Project(1, "A", new List<Work>{ new Work(1, "Stuff", dtToday.AddDays(-5), dtToday.AddDays(-3)), new Work(2, "Things", dtToday.AddDays(-5), dtToday.AddDays(-3)) }),
        new Project(2, "B", new List<Work>{ new Work(3, "More Stuff", dtToday.AddDays(-3), dtToday), new Work(4, "More Things", dtToday.AddDays(-3), dtToday) })
      };

      var hunt = dtToday.AddDays(-2);

      var projectForMoreStuff = projectsAndWork.Where(x => x.Hours.Any(y => y.Start <= hunt && y.End >= hunt));

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
```

Note this will return the whole structure for the Project and all it's children you could do a '.Select(x => new Project(x.ID, x.ManagerName, null)) to just scope to the parent object.  Else it will give you the parent and ALL of it's children.  But this is a way to traverse down a level or two, get what you want, and return the structure as is that matches that criteria.